# gRPC Web compilation with Emscripten

Tags: grpc, cross-platform, webassembly, emscripten

**Can I compile gRPC to the Web with Emscripten?**

NOTE: I'm trying to compile it but it keeps giving errors, please help,

NOTE: Without gRPC-Web.

Thanks.

I am compiling gRPC cross platform and I was able to compile it everywhere except the Web side.
I'm getting a few general errors, I'm solving them as a result of research, but new ones are being added:

- clang++: error: unsupported argument '-g' to option '-Wa,'
- error: "Could not auto-detect platform"
- grpc error: unknown type name 'gpr_atm'
- emcc: error: libz.a: No such file or directory ("libz.a" was expected to be an input file, based on the commandline arguments provided)
- wasm-ld: error: --shared-memory is disallowed by ex_data.c.o because it was not compiled with 'atomics' or 'bulk-memory' features.
- fatal error: 'sys/eventfd.h' file not found **and** fatal error: 'sys/epoll.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you realize the amount of work that is needed to port it to WASM. It is a platform after all. It is comparable to a port to Windows or macOS.

You will need to understand and modify the makefiles to fix the compiler options.

But this is only the beginning.

`libz` for example has been ported - you will have to get it, compile it and include it in your project.

But when it comes to `epoll` or `eventfd` - well, these simply do not have direct equivalents in the web world. You will have to reimplement parts of the code.

Shared memory requires that you compile with `-pthread` and your web server has COOP/COEP enabled - google it for more information - you will need `SharedArrayBuffer`.

This is an absolutely huge undertaking and you will have to learn a lot about both `gRPC` internals and the WASM world.